# Identical Parent and Child classes while using inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am creating a Battleship game for a final project and I am having some difficulties in creating the derived classes. For the game, hits don't matter, just to make it simpler. How can I create the classes to be different to effectively use inheritance or how can I have a parent class (e.g. Ship) and a child class (e.g. Carrier) have the same methods and properties?

Update: Here is the current code I have for my .h file. The biggest problem I am having is that I am required to use inheritance, but don't know how to make the derived classes unique.

```
class Ship{
private:
    int x1, x2, y1, y2; // Position of the ends of the ship
    int size; // Size of the ship
    int hits; // Amount of hits the ship can take
    //int damage[]; // Damage taken
public:
    Ship(); // Default constructor
    Ship(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2); // Parameterized constructor

    int getSize() const;
    void setSize(const int& newSize);

    int getHits() const;
    void setHits(const int& newHits);

    ~Ship(); // Destructor
};

class Battleship: public Ship{
private:

public:
    void setSize(int newSize);
    int getSize() const;
    void setHits(int newHits);
    int getHits() const;

};

class Cruiser: public Ship{
private:
public:
    void setSize(int newSize);
    int getSize() const;
    void setHits(int newHits);
    int getHits() const;
};

class Submarine: public Ship{
private:
public:
    void setSize(int newSize);
    int getSize() const;
    void setHits(int newHits);
    int getHits() const;
};

class Destroyer: public Ship{
private:
public:
    void setSize(int newSize);
    int getSize() const;
    void setHits(int newHits);
    int getHits() const;
};
```

Comment: Why are you trying to create derived classes if they would be identical?

Comment: Please show us your code and how it didn't work. Remember that polymorphism requires using pointers or references and only `virtual` method can be overridden in child classes.